# How to get all information for a product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog

I.m trying to get all information for magento catalog products.
I've tried

```
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

but I want to get all attributes for that product( `categoryIds` is one of them).

Comment: Use This Link
http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/retrieving-product-information-in-magento/ For The More Information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    //get other stuff from the $product
}
```